# Problems to populate dropdown list with options from one of my tables (which already in Models.py)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I'm a newbie and I'm stuck while trying to populate a dropdown list with the records in one on my tables (mysql), my idea is to get this data from Marcasmodelos, and use it as to be posted with another field to my table "Modelos". But whenever rendering, nothing happens, it only shows the default option.

Here are my codes:

models.py

```
class Marcasmodelos(models.Model):
    marca = models.CharField(db_column='Marca', primary_key=True, max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'marcasmodelos'


class Modelos(models.Model):
    modelo = models.CharField(db_column='Modelo', primary_key=True, max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
    marca = models.CharField(db_column='Marca', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'modelos'
```

forms.py

```
class MarcasForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        marca=Marcasmodelos
        fields= '__all__'

class ModeloForm(forms.Form):
    marca = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Marcasmodelos.objects.all().values(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select'}))
    modelo = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

formModelos.html (my form)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="marca">Marca:</label>
                <select name="marca" class="form-control custom-select" id="marca">
                    <option value="">Selecciona una marca</option>
                    {% for marca in marcas %}
                      <option value="{{ marca.id }}">{{ marca }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="col-fluid">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="modelo" class="form-label">Modelo</label>
                <input type="{{ campo.field.widget.input_type }}"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="modelo"
                    name="modelo"
                    placeholder="Modelo del Producto">
                {% if campo.errors %}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ campo.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancelButton">Cancelar</button>
```

CargaModelos.html (my template)

```
{% extends 'master.html' %}

{% block title %}
Carga Modelos
{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="card mx-auto">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="card-header">
            Ingresar nuevo Modelo
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {% include 'Compras/formModelos.html' %}
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted"></div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def CargarMarcas(request):
    CargaMarca = MarcasForms(request.POST or None)
    if CargaMarca.is_valid():
        CargaMarca.save()
    return render (request, 'Compras/Marcas.html')

def CargarModelos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModeloForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            marca_id = form.cleaned_data['marca']
            marca = Marcasmodelos.objects.get(id=marca_id)
            modelo = form.cleaned_data['modelo']
            Modelos.objects.create(marca=marca, modelo=modelo)
            return redirect('modelos_lista')
    else:
        form = ModeloForm()
    return render (request, 'Compras/CargaModelos.html', {'form': form})
```

I was trying to obtain the choices for my select from Table Marcasmodelos, the problem is that it doesn't fet a thing, my table in MySQL workbench already got 7 records from CargarMarcas, but now I can't make them to show in my Select for CargaModelos

Comment: Remove the `.values()`

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be improvements om many levels. First of all, we can use a `ForeignKey`, even (or perhaps even especially) since it is not managed:

```
class Modelos(models.Model):
    modelo = models.CharField(db_column='Modelo', primary_key=True, max_length=45)
    marca = models.ForeignKey(db_column='Marca', to_field='marca', max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'modelos'
```

now that this is done, we can easily turn this into a `ModelForm`:

```
class MarcasForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Modelos
        fields = '__all__'
```

we can even define the widget with:

```
class MarcasForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Modelos
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'marca': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select'})}
```

and then it is no longer our problem.

The form then is also cleaner with:

```
def CargarModelos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModeloForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('modelos_lista')
    else:
        form = ModeloForm()
    return render(request, 'Compras/CargaModelos.html', {'form': form})
```

Using a `ForeignKey` will not only make the `ModelForm` easier to generate, but will also make the ORM more expressive since we can define JOINs that follow the `ForeignKey`, etc.

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `CargarModelos`, not <s>`cargar_modelos`</s>.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WIllem, could you have a look on my formModelos.html? I modified the code, since I had pasted the wrong one

Comment: You don't pass `marcas` to the template, so what would `{% fo marca in marcas %}` do? But regardless: manually rendering HTML forms is not a good idea, exactly since if you later would change the queryset in the Django form, it will not reflect in the HTML form...